# How to drop some parts of a text in a column

Tags: python-3.x

I know that this question must have been addressed but I don't seem to find the answer. 
I have a column in my dataframe and I want to drop some parts of a string from a specified character. The string is 'WD-2020-04-115R:WD-2020-03-111'. I want everything gone starting from R such that I remain with WD-2020-04-115. For any string in my column without an R in it, I want to keep it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
data_array = ['WD-2020-04-115R:WD-2020-03-111', 'WD-2020-05-10582', 'WD-2020-05-10575', 'WD-2020-05-10576','WD-2020-05-10574', 'WD-2020-05-10571R:WD-2020-03-10563', 'WD-2020-05-10577', 'WD-2020-04-10571R:WD-2020-03-10562']
for data in data_array:
    t = data.find('R')
    if t < 0:
        dropped = data
    else:
        dropped = data[:t]
    print(dropped)
    #You can either print, append to an array or write to a file
```

Comment: Assume my data = ['WD-2020-04-115R:WD-2020-03-111', 'WD-2020-05-10582', 'WD-2020-05-10575', 'WD-2020-05-10576','WD-2020-05-10574', 'WD-2020-05-10571R:WD-2020-03-10563', 'WD-2020-05-10577', 'WD-2020-04-10571R:WD-2020-03-10562']. How can I go about it?